# Entity Framework Core get hash all elements in table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

There are two servers with their own databases, but they are identical in structure. On the second database, you need to update the data from the first. In order not to overwrite the entire table each time, I want to check first whether there is a difference in the data between the databases. Therefore, I want to calculate the hash of all fields of a specific table through Entity Framework Core, how can I do this?

I found that mssql has a CHECKSUM function, but not always the database type will be mssql .

Comment: Ordinarily you'd use a database system that did the replication work.. using a client based approach as you have suggested will be very low performance

Comment: performance is not so important, there won't be a lot of data

Comment: Seems like using Dapper to download each entire table to a List of a `record` representing the data, then do `second.Except(first)` to reveal all those in second that are not in first (and the other way round for vice versus)

Comment: Check this library [dotmimsync](https://dotmimsync.readthedocs.io/). Probably it may save some of your time.